# I'm having trouble getting my JS variable display within my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, suitescript

```html
<td id = "customerName" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px">Dear&nbsp;<script>document.getElementById("customerName").innerHTML = custName</script>,</td>    </tr>    <tr>
```

I'm creating an email template for the company I work for. I can't seem to get the JS variable `custName` to display within the HTML snippet id'd `customerName` for a table that I've posted above.

EDIT:

Here is my full HTML code, it is a variable within a Javascript program using SuiteScript API

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/email', 'N/record', 'N/search'],function(email, record, search) {
    function beforeLoad(scriptContext) {
     
    }
    function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {

    }
    function afterSubmit(scriptContext) {
     var fromId = 450103; // my internal ID
     var recordToSend = record.load({ //Fake Customer
      type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
      id : 450104, 
      isDynamic: false
     }); 
     
     var salesOrder = record.load({
      type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
      id : 536583,
      isDynamic: false
     }); 
     
     var department = salesOrder.getValue({
      fieldId : 'department'
     });
     
     var departmentNames = ['Fire Pits Direct', 'Fireplace Remote Controls', 'Skytech Fireplace Remotes', 'Spotix', 'Kick Ass Grills', 'Teak Furniture Classics']; 
     var deptName = ""; 
     
     for(var i = 19; i < 25; i++){
      if(i == department){
       deptName = departmentNames[i-19]; 
      }
     }
     
     var subjectForEmail = "Your Order Has Shipped From "+ deptName + "!"; 
     var custName = "This customer";
     
     var emailBody = '<center></center>\
      <table style="border:1px black solid;">\
      <tbody><tr><td><img src="http://www.spotix.com/images/email/Spotix-family-stores_horizontal.jpg" alt="Spotix Family of stores" align="middle"></td> </tr><tr><td bgcolor="#ff880f"><span style="padding-bottom:10px;font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:28px;line-height: 34px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Great News! Your order is on the way...</span></td>\
      </tr>    <tr>     <td id = "customerName" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px">Dear&nbsp;,</td>    </tr>    <tr>\
      <td style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px">We\'ve shipped your {createdfrom}</td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td align="center" bgcolor="#ff880f" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#000000;font-weight: bold;text-align:left;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">Shipping Method - {shipmethod}</td>\
      </tr>    <tr>     <td width="444" align="left" valign="top" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px" bgcolor="#EEE9E7"><b>Ship To</b></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-\
      size:12px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">{shipaddress}<br></td></tr><tr><td width="444" align="left" valign="top" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px \
      3px 10px" bgcolor="#EEE9E7"><b>Tracking Info</b></td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">{shipmethod} \
      {trackingnumbers}</td></tr><tr><td width="444" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td width="444" align="left" valign="top"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="21" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td \
      align="left" bgcolor="#EEE9E7" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px" valign="bottom"><b>Details</b></td> </tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="262"><span style="font-size: 11px;">QTY:&nbsp;{quantity}</span><span \
      style="font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;SKU:</span>{custcol_item_sku}<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="font-size: 11px; white-space: pre;"></span><span style="font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;ITEM:</span>{item.description}</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>\
      </tbody></table>Thanks for your order!Questions? Call us now: Mon-Fri 8-5 CST 888.977.6849<img src="http://www.spotix.com/images/email/Benefits-Member_TP.jpg" alt="Spotix benefits" align="middle">\
      <script>document.getElementById("customerName").innerHTML = custName</script>'; 
      
     
     email.send({
      author: fromId,
      recipients: fromId,
      subject: subjectForEmail,
      body: emailBody,
      isInternalOnly: false
      
     }); 
     
}

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };
    
});
```

```html
var emailBody = '<center></center>\
      <table style="border:1px black solid;">\
      <tbody><tr><td><img src="http://www.spotix.com/images/email/Spotix-family-stores_horizontal.jpg" alt="Spotix Family of stores" align="middle"></td> </tr><tr><td bgcolor="#ff880f"><span style="padding-bottom:10px;font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:28px;line-height: 34px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Great News! Your order is on the way...</span></td>\
      </tr>    <tr>     <td id = "customerName" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px">Dear&nbsp;,</td>    </tr>    <tr>\
      <td style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px">We\'ve shipped your {createdfrom}</td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td align="center" bgcolor="#ff880f" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#000000;font-weight: bold;text-align:left;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">Shipping Method - {shipmethod}</td>\
      </tr>    <tr>     <td width="444" align="left" valign="top" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px" bgcolor="#EEE9E7"><b>Ship To</b></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-\
      size:12px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">{shipaddress}<br></td></tr><tr><td width="444" align="left" valign="top" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px \
      3px 10px" bgcolor="#EEE9E7"><b>Tracking Info</b></td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">{shipmethod} \
      {trackingnumbers}</td></tr><tr><td width="444" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td width="444" align="left" valign="top"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="21" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td \
      align="left" bgcolor="#EEE9E7" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px" valign="bottom"><b>Details</b></td> </tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="262"><span style="font-size: 11px;">QTY:&nbsp;{quantity}</span><span \
      style="font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;SKU:</span>{custcol_item_sku}<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="font-size: 11px; white-space: pre;"></span><span style="font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;ITEM:</span>{item.description}</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>\
      </tbody></table>Thanks for your order!Questions? Call us now: Mon-Fri 8-5 CST 888.977.6849<img src="http://www.spotix.com/images/email/Benefits-Member_TP.jpg" alt="Spotix benefits" align="middle">\
      <script>document.getElementById("customerName").innerHTML = custName</script>';
```

Comment: Where does custName come from? you have to provide more of your code. Add a minimal working/runable example of what you try please

Comment: *clicks "Run code snippet" and sees error message*. So define the missing variable?

Comment: the variable is `var custName = "This customer";`

Comment: Don't litter your DOM with `<script>` tags.  Put **one** `<script>` tag at the **bottom** of your DOM and do manipulation there.  I'm guessing that the DOM isn't even done creating the `<td>` when it parses and runs your `<script>` tag which is part of the problem.

Comment: I'll give this a try

Comment: You haven't actually said what is going wrong . . . is it just that the value is not displaying?  Are you getting an error?  If it is working at all, I would also expect the "Dear," to get wiped out, based on how you've coded it . . . are you seeing that behavior?

Comment: @talemyn Yes, the variable is not displaying. Run the code snippet in my edit of the full html table. You'll see that instead of sayiing `Dear, (the customers name)`, it just says `Dear,`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `custName` without `""` or `''`, Javascript thinks you are referring to a variable. It looks for a variable with the name `custName` but doesn't find it so it throws a `ReferenceError`.

Make sure that custName is a defined variable and is a string. Or, just use a normal string.

```
var custName = 'John';
document.getElementById("customerName").innerHTML = custName;
```

or just use a string.

```
document.getElementById("customerName").innerHTML = 'John';
```

Comment: Sorry I should have put it in the original post. `var custName = "This customer";`

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the script tag at the end to avoid blocking and set `custName` as a string.

```
<td id ='customerName' style='font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px'>
Dear&nbsp;
</td>
<script>document.getElementById("customerName").innerHTML = 'custName'</script>
```

Comment: But custName is a variable within my JS. Wouldn't this just print the string 'custName' instead of using the variable?

Comment: Cool in that case yes `custName` without the quotes will be ok. Just make sure the JS with the variable is above the `<script>`

Answer (score 0):

So, I I'm not familiar with SuiteScript, so I can't address that particular part of the question, but I can tell you that your current code is not entered into the "code snippet" section in a way that will allow it to run correctly.

Right now, your code has only two JS variables, but one is entered into the HTML section, so it is treated as HTML text, rather than JS code (you can see the `var emailBody =` part of the script rendered at the top of the HTML when you run the snippet).

To get your code to even work correctly, you would need it to be set up something like this:

```js
var custName = "This customer";
var emailBody = '<center></center>\
      <table style="border:1px black solid;">\
      <tbody><tr><td><img src="http://www.spotix.com/images/email/Spotix-family-stores_horizontal.jpg" alt="Spotix Family of stores" align="middle"></td> </tr><tr><td bgcolor="#ff880f"><span style="padding-bottom:10px;font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:28px;line-height: 34px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Great News! Your order is on the way...</span></td>\
      </tr>    <tr>     <td id = "customerName" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px">Dear&nbsp;,</td>    </tr>    <tr>\
      <td style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px">We\'ve shipped your {createdfrom}</td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td align="center" bgcolor="#ff880f" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#000000;font-weight: bold;text-align:left;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">Shipping Method - {shipmethod}</td>\
      </tr>    <tr>     <td width="444" align="left" valign="top" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px" bgcolor="#EEE9E7"><b>Ship To</b></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-\
      size:12px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">{shipaddress}<br></td></tr><tr><td width="444" align="left" valign="top" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px \
      3px 10px" bgcolor="#EEE9E7"><b>Tracking Info</b></td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none!important;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px">{shipmethod} \
      {trackingnumbers}</td></tr><tr><td width="444" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td width="444" align="left" valign="top"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="21" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td \
      align="left" bgcolor="#EEE9E7" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000001;padding:3px 0px 3px 10px" valign="bottom"><b>Details</b></td> </tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="262"><span style="font-size: 11px;">QTY:&nbsp;{quantity}</span><span \
      style="font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;SKU:</span>{custcol_item_sku}<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="font-size: 11px; white-space: pre;"></span><span style="font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;ITEM:</span>{item.description}</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>\
      </tbody></table>Thanks for your order!Questions? Call us now: Mon-Fri 8-5 CST 888.977.6849<img src="http://www.spotix.com/images/email/Benefits-Member_TP.jpg" alt="Spotix benefits" align="middle">';

//insert the email body into the HTML
document.getElementById("emailBodyTarget").innerHTML = emailBody;
//insert the customer name into the email body
document.getElementById("customerName").innerHTML = custName;
```

```html
<div id="emailBodyTarget"></div>
```

**However . . .**

When you run that, you can see that it inserts the customer name, but it also overwrites the "Dear, " text from the template, because it is also contained within the "customerName" `div` that you targeted with your JavaScript.

So, what I would recommend is one of two alternate approaches (going to shorten the code snippets, for simplicity's sake):

1. Create the HTML separately fro the JavaScript, include targeted `span` wrappers for each piece of the HTML template that you'd like to update with data, and insert the data with JavaScript after the HTML is loaded.  This would look something like this:

```js
var custName = "This customer";

//insert the customer name into the email body
document.getElementById("customerName").innerHTML = custName;
```

```html
<table style="border:1px black solid;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:3px 10px 3px 10px">
      Dear&nbsp;,
      <span id="customerName"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this case:
 - the HTML is created and maintained separately from the script that processes the data,
 - the HTML is added to the page first, and the data is added afterwards, and
 - only the customer name data is contained in the new "target `span` elements", so all static, templated content remains untouched.

2. Create the template dynamically using JS, but use placeholders in the template string, and use the JavaScript string `.replace()` method to update the template with customer data, before adding it to the page.  This would look something like this:

```js
var custName = "This customer";
var emailBody = '<table style="border:1px black solid;">\
                   <tr>\
                     <td style="padding:3px 10px 3px 10px">Dear&nbsp;, {[{customerName}]}</td>\
                   </tr>\
                 </table>';

//replace the "customerName" placeholder in the template with the actual customer name 
emailBody = emailBody.replace("{[{customerName}]}", custName);

//insert the email template into the HTML
document.getElementById("emailBodyTarget").innerHTML = emailBody;
```

```html
<div id="emailBodyTarget"></div>
```

In this case:
 - the HTML is created as part of the script that processes the data,
 - the HTML is only added to the after the data has been inserted into the template string, and
 - the data placeholders are the only parts of the template that are replaced by the customer data, so (again) all static, templated content remains untouched.

Either approach should work just fine (I included both in case one works better with SuiteScript than the other).  The key is to make the locations in the template where you want the data to be added to be completely distinct from the rest of the template that should be unchanged, and to target those locations specifically, when you are inserting the customer data.